# VBA- Put range of values into array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm a pretty new self-taught programmer and I hope to learn from all of you.

Here, I'd like to put columns A of excel into an array and form a combination of three columns. The code is written and it runs, however, in a very slow speed.

1. If I put Array(1,2,3...,9,10) it works. However, if I define the 
   Dim nums(): nums = Array(Range("A1:A5").Value) it does not work.
2. Even if I put Array(1,2,3...,9,10), the code runs very slowly.

The following is necessary because it's gonna be used when my array gets long. Indeed, my array would get over 2 thousand combinations. (Values of column A would change).

```
For x = 0 To 60
    For y = 0 To 2
        Cells(x + 1, y + 2).Value2 = arValues(x, y)
    Next
Next
```

My entire code below,

```
Sub AllCombinations()

    Dim nums(): nums = Array(Range("A1:A5").Value)
    Dim arValues(999999, 5)
    Dim n1 As Integer, n2 As Integer, n3 As Integer, n4 As Integer, n5 As Integer, n6 As Integer, x As Long
    Dim y As Integer

    For n1 = 0 To UBound(nums)
        For n2 = n1 + 1 To UBound(nums)
            For n3 = n2 + 1 To UBound(nums)

                arValues(x, 0) = nums(n1)
                arValues(x, 1) = nums(n2)
                arValues(x, 2) = nums(n3)

                x = x + 1

            Next
        Next
    Next

    For x = 0 To 60
        For y = 0 To 2

            Cells(x + 1, y + 2).Value2 = arValues(x, y)

        Next
    Next

    For x = 61 To 120
        For y = 0 To 2

            Cells(x - 60, y + 6).Value2 = arValues(x, y)

        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

[image: Here is a preview of the data]

Comment: I don't follow what you mean.  _Here, I'd like to put Columns A of excel into an array and forms combination of three Columns._.  What combinations?  E.g. If you've got numbers 1 - 10 how do you get that into a combination of three columns?

Comment: Thanks Darren. My bad. A simple example. 1-10, could be grouped as 1,2,3 and 1,3,4 and 1,4,5 so on and so forth. So it is basically Combination without repetition

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook, Let me narrow down the issues. The issue only happens when I try to define Sheets Col. A's values into an Array. It works perfect (Just slow) when it was explicitly defined {1,2,3,...,10}

Comment: What issue?  _I'd like to put columns A of excel into an array and form a combination of three columns. The code is written and it runs, however, in a very slow speed._  You said it works perfectly just slowly - is speed the issue?  If it is then [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is probably better suited.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook, No. I'd like to reference the array to a range. If I define the Dim nums(): nums = Array(Range("A1:A5").Value) it does not work. The error would be  "Execution phase error 9. Array index out of range"

Comment: It depends on how you want it to work.  That code _works_ :   `UBOUND(Nums(0))` returns 5.  `Nums(0)(1,1)` returns the value from A1, `Nums(0)(2,1)` returns the value from A2, etc.  While `Dim nums(): nums = Range("A1:A5")` will return:  `ubound(nums)` returns 5, `nums(1,1)` returns the reference to A1, `nums(2,1)` to A2, etc.  Then again, and **I think this is the one you're after**, `Dim nums(): nums = Application.Transpose(Range("A1:A5"))` returns `UBOUND(Nums)` returns 5.  `Nums(1)` returns the value in A1, `Nums(2)` returns the value in A2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Dim nums()
nums = Range("A1:A5").Value
```

The `nums` array will look like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But it shows undefined arValues(x, 0) = nums(n1) in return. But if I directly set the array = (1,2,3...,10), it works.

Comment: The array has 2 dimensions because a range has 2 dimensions. `nums(1,1)` will contain the value of Cell A1, `nums(3,1)` = A3, , `nums(4,1)` = A4...

Comment: understood this part. But the thing is after adopting your change, the code stops at arValues(x, 0) = nums(n1).

Comment: so change it to `arValues(x, 0) = nums(n1,1)` ?

Comment: it's the same, the error: Execution phase error 9. Array index out of range

Comment: Just noticed your code starts at `0`. As you'll see from my answer the array starts at `1`. So your `For` loop needs to look like: `For n1 = 1 To UBound(nums)`

Comment: Thanks it works...another issue comes as my array contains over 900 numbers...and the combination takes 900 choose 3

Comment: So there is a memory issue...let me refine the loops to see if it could be tackled

Comment: out of Curiousity, May I know when Dim ArValues(X,Y). What're the maximum values of X I could give? Seems if the ArValues have been too big, it'll always come up with error. Indeed, I need to cater for over 100,000,000 combination. Seems the Max of X could only amount to 99,999,999...Any ideas could overcome this?

Comment: My set up allows 178,956,969 on a single dimension array. If I go to 2 dimensions, the total number of values can't be more than 178,956,969.